# Boxplot GLM with binomial errors - interpret summary

Tags: r, bioinformatics, generalized-linear-model, lm

My apologies, I am not even sure how to phrase this question clearly.

I am essential trying to get meaningful statistics to present tomorrow.

All I have managed is this. However, I am very confused how to phrase the descriptive statistics or whereabouts they even are.

I am trying to come up with something like: The wasps are negatively affected by the chemical treatment. The control significantly differs from 2ppb and 10ppb. I am after F and p values and maybe n values I think?

[image: Box plot for chemical 1]

[image: Box plot for chemical 2]

[image: Box plot for chemical 3]

Comment: Perhaps relevel the Treatment levels so that the `Control` comes first then `2ppb` and then `10ppb` and it will make more sense. Other than that I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

### Factor Significance

For interpretation, you want to perform an ANOVA on the fit model, rather than simply interpreting the significance of the coefficients, which is what `summary` is showing you.  The F test is not appropriate for binomial response family, instead you use Chi-squared.  For example,

```
> anova(imdglm, test = "Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: cbind(Correct, Incorrect)

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


          Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                         35     79.636              
Treatment  2   24.123        33     55.514 5.779e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

### More Appropriate Levels

You may want to reconsider the way you are currently processing the treatments.  Your code treats them as categorical, whereas they are dosage levels, which are cardinal.  A more appropriate approach would be to either treat the treatment levels as ordered:

```
imd$Treatment <- factor(imd$Treatment, levels = c("Control", "2bbp", "10bbp",
                        ordered = TRUE))
```

or introduce a new column for the dosage amount (0, 2, or 10), and use that as the explanatory variable in the glm.